# How I can get 2 CheckBox list to 1 form without mapping for 1 model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I created some component with CheckBox list's, for example:

```
<form id="taskForm" asp-action="SetTasksView" asp-controller="Main" method="post" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-update="#taskList" data-ajax-loading="#spinner" data-ajax-success="filterOnSuccess" data-ajax-mode="replace">
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("CategoryWidget", new { categories = ViewBag.UserFilter != null ? ViewBag.UserFilter.Categories : null })
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("ExchangesWidget", new { Exhanges = ViewBag.UserFilter != null ? ViewBag.UserFilter.Exchanges : null })
</form>
```

Which implement:

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="wt-checkboxholder scroller" id="style-1">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Name)
            <span class="wt-checkbox">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].Enabled, new { onclick = "CheckCheckBoxChecked()" })
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].Enabled, Model[i].Name)
            </span>
        }
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

And:

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="wt-checkboxholder scroller" id="style-1">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <span class="wt-checkbox">
                @*@{bool a = test.Any(x => x.Id == Model[i].Id);}*@
                @Html.CheckBox($"[{Model[i].Id}].categories", new { Id = Model[i].Id })
                @Html.Label("categories", Model[i].Name, new { @for = Model[i].Id })
            </span>
        }
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

In controller I have this code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SetTasksView(IEnumerable<ExchangeViewModel> ExchangeViewModels,
                                              OrderPriceViewModel priceModel,
                                              IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel> categories)
{
    var task = /// code

    return PartialView("_ListTask", tasks);
}
```

But when I press button for first form I get only model for ExchangeViewModels, why? How I can split 1 CheckBox, and 2 CheckBox? I think that I am missing some kind of id for mapping the transmission in the controller, but I don't know which one

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can set prefix for model in controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SetTasksView(IEnumerable<ExchangeViewModel> ExchangeViewModels,
                                          OrderPriceViewModel priceModel,
                                          [Bind(Prefix = "Category")] IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel> categories)
```

And this prefix I added to name for checkbox

```
<fieldset>
<div class="wt-checkboxholder scroller" id="style-1">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.Hidden($"Category[{i}].Id", Model[i].Id)
        <span class="wt-checkbox">
            @Html.CheckBox($"Category[{i}].Enabled", new { Id = Model[i].Id })
            @Html.Label("Category", Model[i].Name, new { @for = Model[i].Id })
        </span>
    }
</div>
```

Then I can get the necessary data into different lists of checkboxes